# Entity Framework String would be truncated Error

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, truncated

I have a flat-file SQL Server database. I'm trying to insert info into the table but I keep getting "String or binary data would be truncated" errors every time I run it. ALL of my text fields are nvarchar(max), but it still throws the error and I can look at the data, and nothing is over 8192 characters. I don't think anything is over 256, to be honest.

Any ideas?

I'm using Visual Studio 11 and Entity Framework 4 if that matters.

Comment: I would diagnose this by removing fields until it works then you can look at the actual field which has an issue.

Comment: I would use SQL profiler and capture the problematic query. Then you can check what fields are passed as string and if parameter for string has correct length.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2019 should produce a different error message that contains the table and the column that causes the conflict

> Error message ID 8152 has been replaced with error 2628 to now include the column and string value that would be truncated.
>   “String or binary string would be truncated in table , column . Truncated value: ”

See also https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_server_team/string-or-binary-data-would-be-truncated-replacing-the-infamous-error-8152/

> Note that for now, even in SQL Server 2019 CTP 2.0 the same trace flag 460 needs to be enabled. In a future SQL Server 2019 release, message 2628 will replace message 8152 by default.